# How to make a singe query with the following 3 queries?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 mysql queries everytime I'm running these 3 queries to get data from the mysql. How I can make these 3 queries into singe query. Belw I'm adding the queries.

```sql
SELECT    b.name as projectname,
          bu.configuration,
          bu.floorpla,
          bu.sqft,
          bu.project_id 
FROM      projects b 
    JOIN  project_units bu ON
          bu.project_id=b.id
    AND   b.is_deleted=0 
WHERE     project_id=?
    AND   bpu.configuration=?
    AND   bu.towername=?
    AND   bu.is_deleted=0
ORDER BY  bu.configuration,
          bu.tower_name
```

```sql
SELECT    b.name as project_name,
          bu.configuration,
          bu.floorpla,
          bu.sqft,
          bu.project_id 
FROM      projects b 
    JOIN  project_units bu ON
          bu.project_id=b.id
    AND   b.is_deleted=0 
WHERE     project_id=?
    AND   bu.configuration=?
    AND   bu.is_deleted=0 
ORDER BY  bu.configuration
```

```sql
SELECT    b.name as project_name,
          bu.configuration,
          bu.floorpla,
          bu.sqft,
          bu.project_id 
FROM      projects b 
    JOIN  project_units bu ON
          bu.project_id=b.id
    AND   b.is_deleted=0 
WHERE     project_id=?
    AND   bu.is_deleted=0 
ORDER BY bu.configuration
```

Comment: Can you use a UNION ALL on these queries?

Comment: not with UNION ALL I need to write this as single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this..?

```
SELECT b.NAME AS projectname,
       bu.configuration,
       bu.floorpla,
       bu.sqft,
       bu.project_id

FROM   projects b
       JOIN project_units bu ON bu.project_id = b.id AND b.is_deleted = 0

WHERE  project_id=? AND bu.is_deleted=0 

ORDER  BY bu.configuration, bu.tower_name
```

Or this...

```
SELECT b.NAME AS projectname,
       bu.configuration,
       bu.floorpla,
       bu.sqft,
       bu.project_id

FROM   projects b 
       JOIN project_units bu ON bu.project_id = b.id AND b.is_deleted = 0

WHERE  bu.is_deleted = 0
       AND ( ( project_id = ? AND bu.configuration = ? AND bu.towername = ? )
              OR ( project_id = ? AND bu.configuration = ? )
              OR ( project_id = ? ) )

ORDER  BY bu.configuration, bu.tower_name
```

Select the query depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `union all`

```sql
SELECT    b.name as projectname,
          bu.configuration,
          bu.floorpla,
          bu.sqft,
          bu.project_id 
FROM      projects b 
    JOIN  project_units bu ON
          bu.project_id=b.id
    AND   b.is_deleted=0 
WHERE     project_id=?
    AND   bpu.configuration=?
    AND   bu.towername=?
    AND   bu.is_deleted=0
ORDER BY  bu.configuration,
          bu.tower_name
UNION ALL

SELECT    b.name as project_name,
          bu.configuration,
          bu.floorpla,
          bu.sqft,
          bu.project_id 
FROM      projects b 
    JOIN  project_units bu ON
          bu.project_id=b.id
    AND   b.is_deleted=0 
WHERE     project_id=?
    AND   bu.configuration=?
    AND   bu.is_deleted=0 
ORDER BY  bu.configuration

UNION ALL

SELECT    b.name as project_name,
          bu.configuration,
          bu.floorpla,
          bu.sqft,
          bu.project_id 
FROM      projects b 
    JOIN  project_units bu ON
          bu.project_id=b.id
    AND   b.is_deleted=0 
WHERE     project_id=?
    AND   bu.is_deleted=0 
ORDER BY bu.configuration
```